# How does GoogleSearch pre-renders images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, performance

I've noticed something I didn't see before while doing searchs on google. It concerns images.

[image]

As you can see, while images are loading, Google displays a blank container with image dimensions, AND a background color which corresponds to the average color of each picture.

Now this looks like this, the containing link element has inlined styles including bg color.

```
<a style="height: 56px; margin: 0px; width: 59px; left: 0px; background: rgb(109, 128, 70);"></a>
```

But how do they get it ? How would the client know the average color of a picture before it is loaded ?

Comment: This is a script that can extract the dominant color from an image: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/ • There are several like this. This fork has node support: https://github.com/null2/color-thief

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google do have some idea of what the image is before they show it to you - Perhaps even a copy. To even show up in the search results the image must be in the some form of database along with keywords and information about the image, to allow people to search for it. When the Googlebot crawler discovers the image it must register it's knowledge of the image to the Google servers. It's probably not too hard for the server (or perhaps the bot) to analyse the image and get an average colour, and store this data along with the other relevant image information.

So, if Google knows the average image colour, it is possible to send that colour as the background of the div with the rest of the HTML. This means that the colour will load at the same time as the rest of the CSS/HTML, as the style is known as "Blocking" (The page cannot be rendered until the style is processed and applied). Images, however, are not blocking (And take much longer to load than a single style) so the page is shown before all images have been downloaded. In that space between the image being fully downloaded (and displayed on the page), the colour is shown as a placeholder. When the image is downloaded by the client it is placed into it's proper space.

Keep in mind this is only an informed guess but unless a Google engineer comes along you are unlikely to get a 100% accurate answer but I think it's not likely to be far off from this.

[image: image loading demo]

Here's a screenshot of the network panel in chrome. You can see in red the rendering requests/responses that will cause a change in the page, and in blue all the images being loaded after the initial styles and HTML have been processed. The black line illustrates the gap from when the page has been loaded and when the images have all been downloaded.